# difference between SurfaceView's constructor and SurafaceHolder.Callback 's SurfaceCreated

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm trying to understand why should I use a `SurfaceHolder.Callback` where I can do a lot without it. A question raised up I can put some code in the constructor of the main SurfaceView , why should I then use it. What's the difference and what's the situation where I MUST use `SurfaceHolder.Callback`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SurfaceHolder.Callback` notifies you when the surface is created, changed and destroyed.

If you're drawing to the surface in a separate thread (which is what `SurfaceView` is all about) you will want to know that to determine when you can start/stop your drawing.

The surface is not available immediately after it's constructor called. And there will be problems if you draw to a destroyed surface, too.

Comment: so can't I do this in normal view ? I mean drawing in separate thread ?

Comment: does the service view have lifecyle ?

Comment: What do you mean by service view? Surface View? Surface view is a view as any other view. It belongs to an activity. You can draw in surface view from a separate thread. Good for games. See Lunar Lander sample in the SDK.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant SurfaceView. Thanks a lot.